# CRM 2011 Required Attendees field

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I want to know that "Required Attendees" attribute of Appointment is in which database table
in CRM 2011.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is stored in the activitypartybase table.  This table is a bridge between activities and "Parties" (contacts/accounts) that are related to the activity.  The ParticipationTypeMask column tells you which type of relationship is represented.  Required Attendees will have a ParticipationTypeMask value of 5.  Note that I am referencing a 2013 system, but I believe this schema has not changed.

```
select * 
from activitypartybase 
where activityid = [The Guid of your Activity]
and ParticipationTypeMask = 5
```

Comment: Remember to suggest to use the filtered views, querying directly the tables is not supported.

Comment: Yes, what Guido says is correct, especially if you plan to use this query in a manner where other users will access it such as in a report.  Since the question asked about the database table I think I will leave my answer as is.